# Get the page where is loaded iframe on the server side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, security, iframe

Suppose that we have two sites: **A** and **B**. **`A/embed?code=dummy`** is a page url that is loaded into an `iframe` from **B**.

How can I know if the **A** page is loaded into **B** and not on other site? I want to check this on the server site only (if the site where **A** is loaded **is not `B`**, the page will not be loaded).

I use `req.headers.referer` that returns the expected result, **but** it's a header. It can be modified by the user and this is not secure, I think.

Is there any better alternative? Maybe without using an `iframe`.

From site **A** the user will get an embed code that will be put in site **B**, so basically I have access to the both sites.

Comment: Google `X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM url`

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Hmm.. Not supported in Chrome. Is this secured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see such options:

1) `X-Frame-Options`, which as you said, do not work in Chrome.

2) Inside a frame, you can firstly check `window.parent.location.href`, and if it is `B/...`, load other content with ajax. (Quite safe, browsers don't allow to arbitrarily change location.href.)

3) If you can modify site **B** files, sites **A** and **B** could both generate some key depending on date/time and **B** would pass it as get parameter to `A/embed?code=dummy&tok=...`, then **A** would response only if the key is ok.